# How to calculate the radiance of a pixel

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, pixel

I have a grayscale image and I have the intensity values ​​of all the pixels. I need help converting this pixel intensity value to the radiance of the pixel in W / m2 / sr. If anyone can help me with this, I will greatly appreciate it.

I'm working on getting image features. I have used the MATLAB function 'intensityValue = image(100,300)', to get the intensity for one pixel. The image I am looking at has an object in it so the radiance of the pixels will be different. In a way I am looking to translate the MATLAB colour intensity map to that of a radiance map e.g an intensity of 250 = xxx W/m2/sr.

Kind regards,

Vanessa

Comment: It's hard to help if you don't include your code in the question. Please do include your code.

Comment: what radiation are you talking about? and how is this related to the gray value of an image? radiance is defined for emitters. pixels are usually receivers of radiation

Answer (score 0):

i dont know mathlab but it sounds like basic math scaling problems. So system A should compare in a certain ratio to system B.

if
1/2 = 30/15

then
1/2*30  = 15

and
1/(1/2)*15 =30